# Trying to output 6 random numbers

Tags: php, javascript, random

I'm trying to output 6 random numbers using the following code, however, it gives me a line of 44.  If anyone could help this would be fantastic!

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '
        <script type="text/javascript">
            for(var i=0; i<6; i++){
                var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*43) + 1;
                document.write(x + "</br>");
            }
        </script>
    ';
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing JavaScript with PHP?

Comment: What's the relation between `$row` and the `for` loop within it? They don't seem to depend on each other at all.

Comment: FYI: When it runs, your javascript does its job nicely.

Comment: I'm writing "Javascript with PHP" because the purpose of this code is to output an image stored, which relates to the auto-incremented id in a MySQL table.  I assume that's also the relation? Bit of a newbie to JavaScript @elclanrs

Answer (score 1):

Try to generate a random number with PHP:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++)
      echo rand() . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry guys, really newbie error, I just realised that the while part of the PHP was causing 44 occurrences because it was creating one random number for each of these.  Was a rookie error!

Comment: Consider accepting your own answer so the question will be marked as resolved.